# Handling React-Router routing on ListGroupItem click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I want to link the click of the ListGroupItem with the react router's link.
But I lose the styles of ListGroupItem when I add the Link element.
If I use href instead Link elements, then the page reloads and the partial load is not happening.

```
var NavListGroup = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listgroupInstance = this.props.all_users.map(function(user, index) {
            return (
                <ListGroupItem key={index}><Link to={"/user/"+user.label}>{user.label}</Link></ListGroupItem>
            );
        });
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {listgroupInstance}
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by writing an onClick event. In the onclick event, **browserHistory.push("your_link")** will work.

Please make sure you have at least **react-router 2.0.0** since react-router 1.0.0 has some other history library and this push function was not working for me.

`npm install --save react-router@2.0.0` will do the magic

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

var UserListGroup = React.createClass({
    alertClicked: function(userlabel) {
        browserHistory.push("/user/"+userlabel);
        return true;
    },
    render: function() {
        var listgroupInstance = this.props.all_users.map(function(user, index) {
            return (
                <ListGroupItem key={index}
                    onClick={this.alertClicked.bind(this, user.label)}
                >
                    {user.label}
                </ListGroupItem>
            );
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <div>
               My Render Template
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```